# Unable to install Appium on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: npm, appium, ubuntu-16.04

Is it because of network proxy settings in my machine? Also I am under corporate firewall.

> error:Failed at the appium-chromedriver@2.9.2 install script 'node
>   install-npm.js'

Kindly help me to solve this issue

```
paranth@paranth-ThinkCentre-M73:~$ npm install -g appium
    /home/paranth/.linuxbrew/bin/appium -> /home/paranth/.linuxbrew/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js
    /home/paranth/.linuxbrew/bin/authorize-ios -> /home/paranth/.linuxbrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/.bin/authorize-ios

    > appium-chromedriver@2.9.2 install /home/paranth/.linuxbrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/node_modules/appium-chromedriver
    > node install-npm.js

    info Chromedriver Install Installing Chromedriver version '2.21' for platform 'linux' and architecture '64'
    info Chromedriver Install Opening temp file to write chromedriver_linux64 to...
    info Chromedriver Install Downloading http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.21/chromedriver_linux64.zip...
    info Chromedriver Install Writing binary content to /tmp/201694-10666-t0tuz0.b4lorsh5mi/chromedriver_linux64.zip...
    info Chromedriver Install Extracting /tmp/201694-10666-t0tuz0.b4lorsh5mi/chromedriver_linux64.zip to /tmp/201694-10666-t0tuz0.b4lorsh5mi/chromedriver_linux64
    Invalid or unsupported zip format. No END header found
    /home/paranth/.linuxbrew/lib
    `-- (empty)

    npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /appium/fsevents:
    npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
    npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-38-generic
    npm ERR! argv "/home/paranth/.linuxbrew/Cellar/node/6.7.0/bin/node" "/home/paranth/.linuxbrew/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "appium"
    npm ERR! node v6.7.0
    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.7
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

    npm ERR! appium-chromedriver@2.9.2 install: `node install-npm.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the appium-chromedriver@2.9.2 install script 'node install-npm.js'.
    npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the appium-chromedriver package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     node install-npm.js
    npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    npm ERR!     npm bugs appium-chromedriver
    npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls appium-chromedriver
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /home/paranth/npm-debug.log
    npm ERR! code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To set up android automation in linux:

a) linuxbrew installation: https://github.com/Linuxbrew/linuxbrew 
b) Download and extract android sdk to home folder: http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz 
c) Set android sdk path:

1. Open file by command:

   sudo gedit ~/.bashrc

Add these lines at the end of the file:
adding linux brew path

```
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

#android
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/asci/android-sdk-linux
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Close the file.
Run the command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

e) Run these commands one by one:

1. android

(It will open the sdk manager, and install all the sdk tools from the Tools folder and Android 6.0 API 23)

2. brew install node
3. npm install -g appium
4. appium &

(It will start the appium server needed to run automation)

Answer (score 0):

Get out of firewall or business network and try from a personal data network. It'll work. It worked for me.

Then try "npm install -g appium"